# Excel AddIn using Name Manager

Tags: excel, vba

at work we have some add-ins. Someone got the idea to rename a Sheet, whereupon the Script no longer work. To prevent this from happening in the future, I put the following formula in the worksheet and gave the cell a name using the Name Manager

```
=TEIL(ZELLE("dateiname";A1);SUCHEN("]";ZELLE("dateiname";A1))+1;31)
```

In VBA I use the following script:

```
fileName = "Filename.xlam"
Test = Workbooks (fileName) .Application.Names ("Test")
```

If I set temporarily the isAddIn value to False, everything works without any problems. As an add-in, however, I get error 1004. Can someone help me?
It should be great, if the possibility to get the file name of the xlam add-in via a function, in case someone else comes up with the brilliant idea of renaming this file.

Many thanks for your help

Sam

Comment: Seems like an XY problem to be honest. Using a named range seems like an unreliable workaround. "...if the possibility to get the file name of the xlam add-in " - what is the actual end goal?

Comment: What happens if you use ThisWorkbook instead of Workbooks(filename).Application?

Comment: The advantage of having the filename determined is that I take into account the stupidity of other people who rename everything and have caused me problems before.

Answer (score -1):

I use this method to lock my sheet names: Add this to the worksheet code that you want to lock and then save the sheet. If a user tries to edit the name it will simply revert back to its original name.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> "test" Then
    ActiveSheet.Name = "test"
    End If
    End Sub
```

[source](https://dedicatedexcel.com/how-to-prevent-users-changing-the-worksheet-name-with-vba/)